# How to call stored proc using nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, nhibernate-mapping

I have research about it and all solution are pointing out to one solution, to use the libe of codes below and put it int .hbm.xml file. but I do not have one. What I have is hibernate.cfg.xml and nhvalidator.cfg.xml.

I have read from here : http://forums.asp.net/t/1407518.aspx/1
but where can I type the query tags? I typed it in the hibernate.cfg.xml (see below) but it is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost\MSSQLSERVERR2;Database=SupplierSearch;Trusted_Connection=True</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
        <property name="cache.use_minimal_puts">false</property>
        <property name="use_outer_join">false</property>
    </session-factory>
   <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
  namespace="Quarry.SupplierSearch"
  assembly="SupplierSearch">
    <class name="SupplierSearch" table="Client" lazy="true">
      <id name="ClientId" column="ClientId">
        <generator class="native" />
      </id>

      <property name="FirstName" column="FirstName" />
      <property name="ClientId" column="ClientId" />

      <loader query-ref="GetAllClient"/>
    </class>
    <sql-query name="GetAllClient" >
      <return alias="GetAllClient" class="SupplierSearch">
        <return-property name="ClientId" column="ClientId"/>
        <return-property name="FirstName" column="FirstName"/>
      </return>
      exec GetAllClient 
    </sql-query>
  </hibernate-mapping>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

since it is not working, I tried typing it in my Client.nhv.xml (see below) where client is mapped)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nhv-mapping assembly="Quarry.SupplierSearch" namespace="Quarry.SupplierSearch.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-validator-1.0">
    <class name="Client">
        <property name="Address1">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="Address2">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="BusinessName">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="ClientId">
            <not-null />
            <digits integerDigits="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="Country">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="FirstName">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="LastName">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="ListingType">
            <not-null />
            <digits integerDigits="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="PhoneNumber">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="PostCode">
            <not-null />
        </property>
        <property name="State">
            <not-null />
        </property>
    </class>
  <loader query-ref="GetAllClient"/>
  <sql-query name="GetAllClient">
    <load-collection alias="Clients" role ="Client"/>
    exec [GetAllClient] 
  </sql-query>
</nhv-mapping>
```

any suggestion to get this working? thanks

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be called `Client.hbm.xml` not `Client.hbv.xml`and an embedded resource.

**edit** I not familiar with any tools that generate hbv nor have I ever seen a mapping that begins with `<nhv-mapping .. >`. There must be a custom plugin/dll that you must use to get this working. What tool are you using?

However have you seen this [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/using-stored-procedures-with-nhibernate.html) to get SP's to work without any custom tools.

Comment: did I mention that my solution does not have Client.hbm.xml only client.hbv.xml and hibernate.cfg.xml? The model layer has been generated using a tool and did not generate such file. I tried adding a new file called client.hbm.xml as embedded resource but it returns an error, it can't see the query.

Comment: Please see my edit, the custom tool here is what is causing the problem. I failed to see your mapping begin with `<nhv-mapping..`

Comment: Yes, I have seen a lot of similar posts in the link u provided. It would have been easy if only I have the file client.hmb.xml. Unfortunately none and the client was the one who uses the tool to generate the model layer and he wants it that way. He used Visual NHibernate purchased tool. IS there any other way ? thanks for the help.

Comment: I suspect the tool will be able to see the SP and map it correctly

Answer (score 1):

using stored procedures is not supported with load-collection (scalar only).
use the format:

```
<sql-query name="GetAllClient">
    <load-collection alias="Clients" role ="Client"/>
    SELECT {c.*}
    FROM client c
</sql-query>
```

(with the stuff in your stored proc innards in place of the "SELECT...FROM..." part of course.)